# DrawArc not Closing Edges

Tags: .net, charts, graphics

I made a control to display a circular progress-bar.
The control is shown below:

[image]

- The control works with 2 ARC's:
- One of them displays the current value (blue colored)
- The other one displays the remaining value (red colored).

Both works with ProgressPen and DrawArc from Graphics library.

The problem is that, as you can see, the edges from the two arcs has some pixels between them and they really do not connect - although the angle is a double-number and set exactly to ensure 360 degrees.

In the image above, blue is 90.0 degrees and red is 270.0 degrees (the 25% within circle is just a test of font).

How to avoid this behaviour?

The routine I'm using to draw both arcs is:

```
Private Sub UserControl1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality 
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality

    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias

    e.Graphics.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality


    Dim NewRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(m_X + (20 / 2.0f), m_Y + (20 / 2.0f), m_Width - 20, m_Height - 20)

    DrawProgress(e.Graphics, NewRect, m_Valor)


End Sub


Private Sub DrawProgress(g As Graphics, rect As Rectangle, percentage As integer)

        Dim progressAngle As single = CSng(360.000F / 100.000F * percentage)
        Dim remainderAngle As single = 360.000F - progressAngle
        'create pens to use for the arcs

        Using progressPen As New Pen(m_Color, 20), remainderPen As New Pen(m_EmptyColor, 20)
            g.DrawArc(progressPen, rect, -90.000F, progressAngle)
            g.DrawArc(remainderPen, rect, progressAngle - 90.000F, remainderAngle)
            progressPen.Dispose
        End Using

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I have a perfect circle without the blank-space between RED and BLUE bars?

NOTE: I see that if the bar-width is 1 or 2, the effect is not seen. But I need to have the control able to work even if the width is 20 or more.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I would just draw the blue color as a complete circle and superimpose the red arc over it.

Comment: It's a valid idea, but this control is utilized also do show decreased values - and this way I don't know if the DrawArc command will draw in inverse way (from full-circle to less than 360 degrees...)

Comment: Anyway, I must consider I will waste time to draw an entire circle instead to draw just the necesssary arc.